# Confused on using SimpleDateFormat when converting string value

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I am trying to take a textbox field (represented by the string `wkCreation` field) and convert the data to a date field in "YYYY-MM-DD" format. This is the code I have now using `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
try {
    Date convertdate = format.parse(wkCreation);
    wkCreationFormat = format.format(convertdate) ;
    System.out.println("Convertdate field  = " + convertdate);
    System.out.println("Creation Format field = " + wkCreationFormat);
} 
catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It seems like the only way I can get this to work if the user puts a date actually in the same format as the `SimpleDateFormat` pattern which really defeats the purpose I would think. I am trying to get something in 'mm/dd/yy' or 'mm/dd/yyyy' format to be converted to 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. What am I missing her besides common Java sense? I am thinking my define of `convertdate` is wrong but don't know

Comment: Who fills the text box? Is the date format in it known in advance?

Comment: Ya...that's the way SimpleDateFormat() works. You will need to establish a defined date format that Users will need to use and check to ensure they actually use it. Take 01/02/2015....who is to know which is month and which is day. The best way I found is a DatePicker component, try JDatePicker:  http://jdatepicker.org/

Comment: You need to have a defined input date format to use SimpleDateFormat effectively. Its certainly not a good design to let user enter date by typing. For date, always use calendar. There are so many JS calendar available online. You can chose as per your need.

Comment: it was actually for an input box for a command line.  Text box was incorrect usage there.  From looking at it more it seems the more logical strategy would be to define the input as a date to begin with instead of a string to date to date idea.

Answer (score 1):

Purpose of SimpleDateFormat is to convert String to Date, which is not so easy as you think. If I have date `01/02/2015` how you know that it is February 1st or January 2nd. The answer is, that you do not know, you need additional hint (input) to do the proper conversion - format.

You can write your own format which can support multiple formats, for example something similar to:

```
package q34776322;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;

public class MultiDateFormat {

    String[] supportedFormats;

    public MultiDateFormat(String... formats) {
        supportedFormats = Arrays.copyOf(formats, formats.length);
    }

    public Date parse(String dateString) {
        Date foundDate = null;
        for (String format : supportedFormats) {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
            try {
                Date tmp = sdf.parse(dateString);
                if (foundDate != null) {
                    // correct parsing, but it was at parsed before => error
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unparsable date: '" + dateString + "' (multiple pattern matches)");
                } else {
                    foundDate = tmp;
                }
            } catch (ParseException pe) {

            }
        }
        if (foundDate == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unparsable date: '" + dateString + "' (no pattern match)");
        }
        return foundDate;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MultiDateFormat mdf = new MultiDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", "dd/MM/yyyy");
        mdf.parse("2015-02-01"); // February 1st
        mdf.parse("01/02/2015"); // February 1st again

        mdf = new MultiDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", "dd/MM/yyyy");
        try {
            mdf.parse("01/02/2015");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Expected exception");
        }
    }

}
```

Which is basically trying all formats - if there is no fit or there are multiple fits, exception is thrown...

Answer (score 1):

You are just one step away from the right code. What you missed is the fact that you are dealing with two different date-formats as you said:

> I am trying to **get something in 'mm/dd/yy'** or 'mm/dd/yyyy' format to be **converted to 'YYYY-MM-DD' format**.

In this case you just need two Formatters more or less like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat inputParser = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat outputFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
try {
  Date convertdate = inputParser.parse(wkCreation);
  wkCreationFormat = outputFormatter.format(convertdate) ;
  System.out.println("Convertdate field  = " + convertdate);
  System.out.println("Creation Format field = " + wkCreationFormat);
```

One to parse the expected input, and the other to parse to the desired output.

*To parse the input you of course need to either provide flexibility or clear instructions to the users on the expected format.*

Answer (score 0):

## Strings Are Not Date-Time Objects

Strings are not date-time objects. If you have a string that is a textual representation of a date-time value, you must *parse* that value into a date-time object. Then use that date-time object to *generate* another string as another textual representation of the date-time value in an alternate format. So one format defined for parsing, another format defined for generating.

## Impossible To Parse *Any* Date-Time Format

It is not logically possible to parse a date value from a String using any conceivable format. For example: `1/2/3`… which is the month, the day-of-month, the abbreviated year? You must define for your data-entry users one or more formats expected. Make a parse attempt, catch the expected parse exception, repeat until one works. This has been covered many times on StackOverflow, so search for example code if the idea is not clear.

## java.time

You are using troublesome old date-time classes now supplanted by the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework found in Java 8 and later.

This framework includes a class, [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html), to represent date-only values without a time-of-day nor time zone.

Your two formats for expected inputs must be specified with a coded pattern. The codes are similar to that of java.text.SimpleDateFormat but not exactly the same. Be sure to study the doc carefully.

```
String input = "12/01/2015" ;
DateTimeFormatter formatterInput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM/dd/yyyy" );
try {
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse( input , formatterInput );
}  catch ( DateTimeParseException e ) {
       // FIXME: handle exception
}
```

Your desired output format `yyyy-MM-dd` happens to comply with the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. The java.time framework uses this standard as it defaults in parsing and generating textual representations of date-time values. The [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class holds constants for various ISO 8601 formats including [`ISO_LOCAL_DATE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_DATE), your desired format.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatterOutput = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE ;
String output = localDate.format( formatterOutput );
```